# Magento data feed extension not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I installed data feed extension to export list of all products for comparison, this is plugin http://cpcstrategy.com/magento-data-feed-extension/, in the step 5 my page is empty, feeds are not showing. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: In step 5, by default it will show empty only. But  once you proceed to all the steps and again come back to step 5, then it will display the feeds that are created by u

Comment: I dont have button `Add feed` showed on Step 7.

Comment: Did you try to clear your cache and relogin after installing the extension? Because you must re-login at admin side and clear your cache when you install a new extension.

Comment: yes, but the same problem appears :(

Comment: For your sake, just now I have installed this extension in my magento application and it works fine. I didn't face any issue. Try to install it in another magento application.

Answer (score 0):

Empty Caches and Logout from admin
Re-login at admin

I think your problem will be solved

Comment: deleted cache and re-logged to admin, the same problem appears

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: `Magento ver. 1.7.0.2`